# Is there a way to download all release data of a github repository?

Tags: github, github-api

This picture shows few releases from a project. To see more, one has to press "Next" button.

[image]

Is it possible to get data  (commit hash tag, date) about all releases preferably in a excel, csv, json file format or at least in a single web page.

Answer (score 1):

The [list releases](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#list-releases-for-a-repository) API endpoint will provide data about each release in a repository in JSON format:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/releases
```

The `target_commitish` field returned in the response is the nearest thing to a commit hash that is returned by this API, but you can then use the the Git Data API to [return the commit SHA](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/tags/#get-a-tag):

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo/git/tags/:sha
```

Where `:sha` can be the string returned in `target_commitish`. The result of this request will give you the matching commit SHA in the `sha` field.